# In scenario, where only stored procedures are used for ASP.NET MVC 4 application - is better ADO.NET or EntityFramework 5?

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, ado.net

I want to know your opinion.

In scenario, where only stored procedures are used for data manipulation - is better to use standard **ADO.NET** *or* **Entity Framework 5**.

The only (and main) reason for using EF are strongly typed classes (generated complex classes), that can be used as a model in **ASP.NET MVC 4**. Updating complex types could be simpler in EF compare to ADO.NET.

Reason for using ADO.NET is making communication with database more simply.

Thank you for your opinion.

Comment: I would recommend EF, but that is just me. It's more flexible and offers more support.

Comment: It's my opinion too, but I'm arguing with SW architect :-)

Comment: Then you should quit bugging him, he is always right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also look at e.g. [Dapper-Dot-Net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) (or some of the other "micro-ORM") which is based off "raw" ADO.NET, but also offers conversion to nice .NET objects (the main EF benefit in your case, I believe) from stored procedure results

Comment: Thank you, Dapper-Dot-Net looks good, but there are some cons. Classes must be written manually and regenerating when SP is changed (column count) is not possible. So litte advantage compare to ADO.NET, big disadvantage compare ti EF.

Comment: And another minus... out SW architect will not accept this as solution because it't not well-known technology :-)

Comment: @Tomino: first of all - Dapper is used e.g. on **Stackoverflow** right here - one of the busiest and best-performing sites around. If that's not enough reputation, I really don't know what else your SW architect wants... (yes, it's neither created by IBM nor by Microsoft.....)

Comment: OK, but I'm lazy programmer and I don't want to create classes manually... and regenerate them manually after every DB change :-). Maybe is Dapper great, but this is not an option... options for now are only: ADO.NET and EF 4

Comment: @Tomino: you could **easily** create a code-generation template using T4 in Visual Studio to do this for you ....

Comment: little bit complicated... but I can realize this sollution: generate POCO model (for EF) and then use Dapper-Dot-Net... :-)

Comment: just FYI: Final conclusion was **Dapper**. Fortunately not ADO.NET. We made some testing and we found mapping created by SW Arch. 2-3 times slower than EF5. But Dapper was about 5% faster than EF 5. Reason for SW Arch. to use Dapper, because he hates EF (=doesn't undestand it)